# bin/java not found or not a valid JDK when installing SQLDeveloper 4 on Linux Mint

Tags: java, linux, oracle

I am trying to install sqldeveloper, and followed all the [instructions](https://mikesmithers.wordpress.com/2014/03/26/installing-sqldeveloper-4-on-mint-and-ubuntu-minus-the-alien/) but no avail. Always getting the same error after running `./sqldeveloper.sh` and inserting `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle` as a path (Error: `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/java not found or not a valid JDK`). Any idea what might be going wrong? I would really appreciate any help or tip.

`echo $JAVA_HOME` returns this

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle
```

`java -version`:

```
java version "1.7.0_80"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_80-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.80-b11, mixed mode)
```

`update-alternatives --config java`:

```
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java          1072      auto mode
  1            /opt/java/jdk1.7.0_79/bin/java                   1         manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1071      manual mode
* 3            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java          1072      manual mode
```

I have tried first choice too.

Comment: How about using `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre` for `$JAVA_HOME`? The error message hints some `$JAVA_HOME/bin/java` usage

Comment: this looks like correct.. now it showed different error, that it requires java 8. After download and install, i'll let you know about the result

Comment: Thanks alot! this solved my issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can run 'which java' to find which java is used currently

Comment: `which java` returns `/opt/java/jdk1.7.0_79/bin/java` .  I have also tried other java alternatives but they didn't work too

Answer (score 0):

It is looking for JDK home but your Java home points to JRE. Update path to point to '`/opt/java/jdk1.7.0_79`'. It will solve your problem.

Comment: well, the same error shows up again. And echo `$JAVA_HOME` returns `/opt/java/jdk1.7.0_79` as I run it in the same terminal which I run `sqldeveloper.sh`

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete the folder .sqldeveloper in your home directory, when you do it, try to execute again ./sqldeveloper.sh